# HTML application run external exe on chrome using native messaging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, chrome-native-messaging

Is it possible to run an external exe (under windows) using native messaging from a HTML application (Javascript) ?

Note:
I have a npapi plugin that runs an exe installed in the client machine. now npapi is deprecated, so I need another way to run my external exe from my website.

Comment: possible duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if there is a way for an html page to launch an executable on the client's machine? No, that is not possible. It'd be a huge security hole if it were.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a npapi plugin that runs an exe installed in the client machine. now npapi is deprecated, so I need another way to run an external exe from my website.