# How to create a application link in windows

Tags: c#, windows, url, hyperlink

I am trying to create an application in C# that can be requested by the usage of link like skype do. (eg. skype://etc) forces my browser to open skype. How can i archive this with my application ?

Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate, please look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain something similar, for example, to opening a Magnet URI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) from your browser, then you have to modify the registry using a .reg file like this:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApp]
@="URL:myapp Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApp\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyApp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Obviously you have to change the content fo the file accordingly to where your application is installed and how is called.
If you want to modify the registry during the installation of your app, you can have a look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367530(v=vs.85).aspx