# How to execute/open a FTP/SFTP site in FileZilla from a webpage?

Tags: html, ftp, filezilla

I have a requirement where I need to open an FTP site in FileZilla from a webpage.

I have FileZilla installed on my machine and I have an access to the FTP.
I will be creating a button in a HTML page, upon clicking it, it must open that particular FTP site using FileZilla.

How do I code this in HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an external program, e.g. notepad, using hyperlink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink)

Comment: Make a standard hyperlink, but instead of using "http://...whatever", use "ftp://...link"

Comment: You can configure your Windows OS to handle the URLs in a specific way. Please take a look at this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/186563/associate-ftp-hyperlink-to-filezilla

Answer (score 1):

For a general discussion on running a local application from a webpage, see
[How to run an external program, e.g. notepad, using hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2800081/850848)
In short, you cannot.

---

An FTP client is a special case though, as you can reasonably expect that some application on the client machine handles the `ftp://` URLs.

Note that by default web browsers register to handle the `ftp://`. So you always have a fallback.

But FileZilla does not register itself.

If you have a control over the client machines, you can register FileZilla yourself.

If not, you either accept the webbrowser fallback or rely on a user to have his/her preferred FTP client registered.

One of FTP clients that can [register itself to handle the `ftp://` URL is WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url). Though WinSCP does not register for the `ftp://` specifically by default, as it deliberately leaves the default web browser registration untouched. A uses has to explicitly register the `ftp://` in [WinSCP integration preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_integration). But WinSCP registers its [specific URL prefix, the `winscp-ftp://`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url#winscp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*