# Launching Electron app from a standard web browser

Tags: electron

Clicking a `mailto:` link will open my default mail client. In a similar manner, I would like to launch an Electron app with `my-app:`. What is the best way to achieve this and gracefully fallback to a standard `http` link if the app isn't installed?

Furthermore, I would also like to be able to pass through some extra details `my-app:foo/bar`. How would this be intercepted inside of Electron when it launches?

I have read some docs on what I *think* might be relevant stuff: http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/api/protocol/ however as a frontend dev there's some gaps in my understanding of how the overarching process works. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: did you get this working? I couldn't on linux and chrome.

Comment: there is no accepted answer here, so did you find a working example for this?

Answer (score 11):

Electron has evolved quite a bit since this question was first posted.

You no longer have to dive quite as deep and can skip the Electron protocol API. Instead, use the `app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(protocol[, path, args])` interface and its siblings `app.removeAsDefaultProtocolClient(protocol[, path, args])` and `app.isDefaultProtocolClient(protocol[, path, args])`.

These enable you to register a protocol identifier `your-protocol://` and receive arguments:

> The whole link, including protocol, will be passed to your application
>   as a parameter. [Electron API docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#appsetasdefaultprotocolclientprotocol-path-args-macos-windows)

Comment: do you have an example of this working? I tried it and it's not working for me on linux and chrome.

Comment: do you know if is there a way to add two protocols like that? I mean, that electron-app would open both on your-protocol_0:// and your-protocol_1:// ?

Comment: I haven't actually tried registering multiple protocols for an app, however, I also didn't find any indication of why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible to do what you want to do. Depending on whether you want to launch your Electron app from an actual browser window or simply from another Electron instance.

I found this other Stack Overflow post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink) that shows a workaround (though I'm afraid it won't graciously default to anything) and explains how it could be dangerous to launch programs directly from the browser.

If you want to launch your Electron app from another Electron app however you might want to check this out [link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/child_process.html).