# Can I record my screen/webpage by clicking a button from that html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-recording

I want to add a screen recorder to my html webpage. So i.e. I will have a button and by clicking on that button, to start recording my screen. I know there is such a tool in HTML5 and a JS framework, but I am wondering if it is possible in HTML4. Any suggestions, links are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool for that even in HTML5. You may start a external Application like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink)

Comment: In the company I work, they already have one that works in html5 and told me to see if it is possible in html4. I don't know how they access the screen recorder from html but they have it.

Comment: If you talk about JSCapture then no, there is now way to use it with html4 because of features which are just aviable in html5.