# How can allow my button from app call to open external apps

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this javaScript code:

```
gotoExternalApp = function () { 
    var options = Environment.appOptions; 
    console.log ("Launching " + options.appName); 
    ExternalApp.launch(options); }; 
    gotoExternalApp(); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: So what is the question? External Apps are what?

Comment: What Javascript library or framework is this code supposed to be for? `Environment` and `ExternalApp` are not part of a standard browser environment.

Comment: We need some more detail. What are you really trying to do? What are external apps?

Comment: What I mean is to be able to open other apps for example Google Calendar, Colornote, Dictionary, etc...

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? If so what was it? If not could you please mark the below answer as 'accepted' to improve the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to open these from a web browser? I'm not sure this is possible due to the security restrictions of JavaScript.
You could use activex as they have in this post... [How to run an external program, e.g. notepad, using hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink)