# Launching an application from a browser using HTML?

Tags: ipad, browser

I have been asked by our iPad Admin. to create a link on our intranet that will open the application Filebrowser on student's iPads.  Is there a way to code this in HTML or HTML5?  No icon needed, just a link to open from browser (Safari) on the iPad.

I'm a novice coder, really a front-end designer who often has to find ways to code something so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. See: [How to run an external program, e.g. notepad, using hyperlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800081/how-to-run-an-external-program-e-g-notepad-using-hyperlink)

That being said, you can open a "file browser" when you click on an `<input type="file" />` form tag, to browse and select a file for upload, but I gather that is not what you want.

You can also create a link to a local file, but you'll run into permissions issues. See: [How can I create a link to a local file on a locally-run web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)